# Using apply function works, however using .assign() the same function does not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a bit stuck, I have a working function that can be utilised using `.apply()`, however, I cannot seem to get it to work with `.assign()`. I'd like this to work with assign, so I can chain a number of transformations together.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to resolving the issue?

This works

```
data = {'heading': ['some men', 'some men', 'some women']}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

def add_gender(x):
    if re.search("(womens?)", x.heading, re.IGNORECASE):
        return 'women'
    elif re.search("(mens?)", x.heading, re.IGNORECASE):
        return 'men'
    else:
        return 'unisex'

dataframe['g'] = dataframe.apply(lambda ref: add_gender(ref), axis=1)
```

This does not work

```
dataframe = dataframe.assign(gender = lambda ref: add_gender(ref))
```

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Is this because `.assign()` does not provide an axis argument? So perhaps the function is not looking for the right thing?

Having read the documentation `.assign` states you can generate a new column, so I assumed the output would be the same as `.apply(axis=1)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) of `DataFrame.assign`:

> **DataFrame.assign(**kwargs)**
>
> (...)
>
> **Parameters **kwargs : dict of {str: callable or Series}**
>
> The column names are keywords. **If the values are callable, they are computed on the DataFrame** and assigned to the new columns. The callable must not change input DataFrame (though pandas doesn’t check it). If the values are not callable, (e.g. a Series, scalar, or array), they are simply assigned.

This means that in

> ```
> dataframe = dataframe.assign(gender=lambda ref: add_gender(ref))
> ```

`ref` stands for the calling DataFrame, i.e. `dataframe`, and thus you are passing the whole `dataframe` to the function `add_gender`. However, according to how it's defined, `add_gender` expects a single row (`Series` object) to be passed as the argument `x`, not the whole DataFrame.

> ```
> if re.search("(womens?)", x.heading, re.IGNORECASE):
> ```

In the case of `assign`, `x.heading` stands for the whole column `heading` of `dataframe` (`x`), which is a `Series` object. However, `re.search` only works with `string` or `bytes`-like objects, so the error is raised. While in the case of `apply`, `x.heading` corresponds to the field `heading` of each individual row `x` of `dataframe`, which are `string` values.

To solve this just use `assign` with `apply`. Note that the lambda in `lambda ref: add_gender(ref)` is redundant, it's equivalent to just passing `add_gender`.

```
dataframe = dataframe.assign(gender=lambda df: df.apply(add_gender, axis=1))
```

---

As a suggestion, here is a more concise way of defining `add_gender`, using [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

```
def add_gender(df):
    pat = r'\b(men|women)s?\b'
    return df['heading'].str.extract(pat, flags=re.IGNORECASE).fillna('unisex')
```

Regarding the regex pattern `'\b(men|women)s?\b'`:

- `\b` matches a word boundary
- `(men|women)` matches `men` or `women` literally and captures the group
- `s?` matches `s` zero or one times

[`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) extract the capture group of each string value of the column `heading`. Non-matches are set to NaN. Then, [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) replaces the NaNs with 'unisex'.

In this case, `add_gender` expects the whole DataFrame to be passed. With this definition, you can simply do

```
dataframe = dataframe.assign(gender=add_gender)
```

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'heading': ['some men', 'some men', 'some women', 'x mens', 'y womens',  'other', 'blahmenblah', 'blahwomenblah']}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

def add_gender(df):
    pat = r'\b(men|women)s?\b'
    return df['heading'].str.extract(pat, flags=re.IGNORECASE).fillna('unisex')
```

Output:

```
>>> dataframe 

         heading
0       some men
1       some men
2     some women
3         x mens
4       y womens
5          other
6    blahmenblah
7  blahwomenblah

>>> dataframe = dataframe.assign(gender = add_gender)
>>> dataframe 

         heading  gender
0       some men     men
1       some men     men
2     some women   women
3         x mens     men
4       y womens   women
5          other  unisex
6    blahmenblah  unisex
7  blahwomenblah  unisex
```